# How to change layout of login page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

In  Laravel 8/livewire / Fortify app I want to change layout of login page,
so in file resources/views/auth/login.blade.php I commented  at top of file and tried in
app/Providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php to assign layout, as I do for livewire components :

```
public function boot()
{
    
    Fortify::loginView(function () {
        return view('auth.login', [] )->layout('layouts.private');
    });
```

But It does not work...
How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would [Rendering Components](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components)/Configuring The Layout Component help? "_If you need even more control, you can use the ->layout() method on the view instance you return from render()._"

Comment: I suppose 'auth.login' file does not know anything about livewire...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do further configuration to load the login page if you follow the fortify routes conventions. Fortify is headless authentication library. You can modify it according to your own needs.

However, if we only follow the Fortify routes convention, then we don't need to mess up. Simply put your **login.blade.php** inside `views/auth/login.blade.php` and Fortify will take care of loading it. Now put some stuff like **HTML/CSS** inside `login.blade.php` and hit the website at /login. Then fortify will automatically load it for you.

However, if you don't want to use the same directory structure. i.e to keep your login page somewhere then you can easily tell the fortify inside the boot method of FortifyServiceProvider.php

```
Fortify::loginView(function () {
        return view('admin.login');
});
```

Now whenever you will hit **`/login`**, it will request the fortify to load the login page from `views/admin/login.blade.php`

Comment: I would prefer to follow fortify routes conventions/rules.
So is the best way to edit resources/views/auth/login.blade.php without refering any layouts?